# Office 365 API Ruby sample App is broken

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I've been following the steps for setting up a sample Ruby App at https://dev.office.com/Getting-Started/office365Apis?platform=option-ruby when I run the application and click the button for sign in I get a bad Uri error `bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)` which directs me to line 105 in the omniauth-azure-activedirectory gem. (file azure_activedirectory.rb)

```
  # Constructs a one-time-use authorize_endpoint. This method will use
  # a new nonce on each invocation.
  #
  # @return String
  def authorize_endpoint_url
    uri = URI(openid_config['authorization_endpoint'])
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(client_id: client_id,
                                    redirect_uri: callback_url,
                                    response_mode: response_mode,
                                    response_type: response_type,
                                    nonce: new_nonce)
    uri.to_s
  end
```

After further investigation, I'm getting an invalid tenant error.
Pry shows: [pry image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S03yP.png)
  The odd thing is, if I run the node.js and angular sample apps under the same tenant, it runs fine as expected with no problem.  There seems to be some disconnect with the gem and the way it queries Microsoft Graph api...

Answer (score 2):

At that point, the gem is just trying to redirect you to the authorization URL. I guess it's having some issue with your domain moser-inc.onmicrosoft.com.

Is this the same domain that appears in your `/config/environment.rb` file?

I'm wondering if the library has some problems with hyphens.

Just to confirm, you never had a chance to type credentials, right?
Could you try from an incognito window?

Comment: Yes its the same as in the environment.rb file, which is autogenerated anyways from the site.  Thankfully I found this site https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2142 which provided a walkthrough that didn't use that omniauth-azure gem.  I was just looking for something to work off of, so problem resolved.  https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2142

Comment: and i agree, i think the `-` was part of the issue

Answer (score 2):

There's a site https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2142  here that provides a step by step walkthrough, found it very helpful for anyone that encounters the same problem i did.